# question about variance of a reference month(calculate)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this mesure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQIoJ.png)
How can I change the measure to get the result below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER0Wc.png)by adding a slicer to choose the reference month.
thanks.

I add a parameter Mois normalise = Format(Dates[Date],"MMMM")
change the '01' to mois normalise, but doesn't work

Comment: Please paste code as text and not as images. Please add more detail to your question as it is unclear what you are trying to do. You want to calculate the difference of the selected month in the slicer with the current row of the table?